# Laravel Eloquent - Pivot Table

Tags: laravel

i have this tables:

```
Attendances
id | member_id
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3

Members
id | name
1  | Joe
2  | Jane
3  | David

Positions
id | position_name
1  | art
2  | singer
3  | dancer

member_position
member_id | position_id
1         | 2 
1         | 1
1         | 3
2         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 3
```

From Attendances table, how can i select all who attended that are singers using laravel eloquent?

====EDIT=====

Attendance model:

```
public function member()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
}
```

Member model:

```
public function positions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Position');
}
```

Position model:

```
public function members() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member');
}
```

Comment: Attach your models relations

Comment: @IndianCoding - added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use whereHas method with nested relations.

```
$attendances = Attendance::with('member')
    ->whereHas('member.positions', function($query){
        $query->where('id', 2);
    })
    ->get();

foreach($attendances as $attendance){
    echo $attendance->member->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm positive this will give you the attendances whose member is a singer, with a nested member relationship model.

```
$attendances = Attendance::whereHas('member.positions', function($query) {

   $query->where('position_name', 'singers');

})->with('member')->get();
```

And then, you can iterate through your results as so:

```
foreach($attendances as $attendance){
    echo $attendance->member->id;
    echo $attendance->member->name;
}
```